# Any side effects of changing a parameter in modifyselection of CKEditor 5?

Tags: ckeditor5

We are using CKEditor 5. Using arrow keys in image captions causes a problem. Hitting left or right arrow when the cursor is at the beginning or end of the caption, respectively, causes a temporary freeze. We found that the `skip` function in ckeditor5-engine\src\model\treewalker.js is the culprit. Depending on the length of the document, the loop may take 100K iterations, till it reaches the first or last element of the document. If we change the passed in parameter in `tryExtendingTo` function of ckeditor5-engine\src\model\utils\modifyselection.js to `false`, the problem vanishes. Inspection does not arise any problems, but we want to be sure why this is given as `true` in the first place and if there would be any unforeseen side effects.

```
data.walker.skip( () => true );
```

Arrows in captions of CKEditor 5 demo work differently. Cursor does not go out with arrow keys, left arrow works as home key and right arrow works as end key. So, copying the behavior of the demo is not an option.

Comment: You write that this issue doesn’t occur on the official demo. This means that you added or modified some features or that something unrelated is different in your app. You should focus on tracking those things and report a bug (cause it seems that you’re hitting one). Asking question here is a bit pointless because we’d need to guess what’s the problem.

Comment: Actually I did not say it does not occur on the official demo, but did not give explicit details, sorry about that. Append a lot of paragraphs/tables/lists to demo editor, then keep down-arrow pressed while cursor is on monk picture's caption and it will freeze. Up arrow would not cause a freeze in this case. Insert content before the image and keeping up-arrow pressed will cause a freeze this time. This suggests processing time is correlated with the amount of content in the direction of the arrow key pressed.

Comment: Now's better :) Please report it on https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues so the team can check it and fix (if there's a problem). StackOverflow won't help here.

Comment: Thanks Furkan for opening https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1568!